# Need help sorting ArrayList & Calculating averages of test scores

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I tried adding a new class per a suggestion I was given, which is seen at line 67.  I am unsure how to link the new class with the entries created from user input and the goal is to sort the `ArrayList` by the last name and to calculate averages of each of the entries 4 test scores, resulting in an average score - I would like the average score to be added to each students entry and added to the final `ArrayList`

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
 

//information given by user input that will eventually go into the ArrayList 
public class studentInformation {
        

    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {
        
        //creating ArrayList to hold the objects created above
        ArrayList<Object> studentdatabase = new ArrayList<Object>();
        
        char cont;
        do {
            Scanner fnInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's First Name & Press Enter");
            //String fn = fnInput.nextLine();
            studentdatabase.add(fnInput.nextLine());
        
            Scanner lnInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Last Name & Press Enter");
            //String ln = lnInput.nextLine();
            studentdatabase.add(lnInput.nextLine());
        
            Scanner score1Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's First Exam Score & Press Enter");
            //int score1 = score1Input.nextInt();
            studentdatabase.add(score1Input.nextInt());
        
            Scanner score2Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Second Exam Score & Press Enter");
            //int score2 = score2Input.nextInt();
            studentdatabase.add(score2Input.nextInt());
        
            Scanner score3Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Third Exam Score & Press Enter");
            //int score3 = score3Input.nextInt();
            studentdatabase.add(score3Input.nextInt());
            
            
            Scanner score4Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Fourth/Final Exam Score & Press Enter");
            //int score4 = score4Input.nextInt();
            studentdatabase.add(score4Input.nextInt());
            
            
            Scanner continueInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 'C' to end or 'A' to Add More");
            cont = continueInput.next().charAt(0);
            
            //calculate the average score for each student 
            
            
            //sort the ArrayList prior to printing
            //Collections.sort(studentdatabase);
            
            //Prints out the arrayList
            System.out.println(studentdatabase);
        }
        while(cont != 'c' || cont != 'C');
        
    }
    
    class Students {
        String firstName, lastName;
        int firstScore, secondScore, thirdScore, fourthScore, averagescore;
        char lettergrade;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't create more than one `Scanner` on `System.in`. --- 2) Don't add the information to an `ArrayList`. --- 3) Rename class `Students` to `Student`, since one instance of the class only represents one student. --- 4) Create an instance of `Student` using the `new` operator. See your Java learning guide for how. --- 5) Assign the values entered by user to the fields of the `Student` instance you created. --- 6) *... ok, let's start there and see how far you get ...*

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, create a real Student class (singular, not plural). An instance of this class is only one student. It will handle average calculation in a dedicated method.

Think about using getters and setters with the correct accessors on your attributes.

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName, lastName;
    private int firstScore, secondScore, thirdScore, fourthScore, averagescore;
    private char lettergrade;

    public float computeAverage(){

        int sum = firstScore + secondScore + thirdScore + fourthScore;

        return (float) sum / 4;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getFirstScore() {
        return firstScore;
    }

    public void setFirstScore(int firstScore) {
        this.firstScore = firstScore;
    }

    public int getSecondScore() {
        return secondScore;
    }

    public void setSecondScore(int secondScore) {
        this.secondScore = secondScore;
    }

    public int getThirdScore() {
        return thirdScore;
    }

    public void setThirdScore(int thirdScore) {
        this.thirdScore = thirdScore;
    }

    public int getFourthScore() {
        return fourthScore;
    }

    public void setFourthScore(int fourthScore) {
        this.fourthScore = fourthScore;
    }

    public int getAveragescore() {
        return averagescore;
    }

    public void setAveragescore(int averagescore) {
        this.averagescore = averagescore;
    }

    public char getLettergrade() {
        return lettergrade;
    }

    public void setLettergrade(char lettergrade) {
        this.lettergrade = lettergrade;
    }
}
```

Then, don't use Object in your list but Student. You created an object. Use it !

You can't sort the list until you're done with feeding it. Put the sort out of the loop.

```
cont != 'c' || cont != 'C'
```

will always be true. So you will never get out of your loop.

Finally, I would suggest something like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {

        //creating ArrayList to hold the objects created above
        ArrayList<Student> studentdatabase = new ArrayList<Student>();

        char cont;
        do {

            Student currentStudent = new Student();

            Scanner fnInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's First Name & Press Enter");
            currentStudent.setFirstName(fnInput.nextLine());

            Scanner lnInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Last Name & Press Enter");
            currentStudent.setLastName(lnInput.nextLine());

            Scanner score1Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's First Exam Score & Press Enter");
            currentStudent.setFirstScore(score1Input.nextInt());

            Scanner score2Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Second Exam Score & Press Enter");
            currentStudent.setSecondScore(score2Input.nextInt());

            Scanner score3Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Third Exam Score & Press Enter");
            currentStudent.setThirdScore(score3Input.nextInt());

            Scanner score4Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Student's Fourth/Final Exam Score & Press Enter");
            currentStudent.setFourthScore(score4Input.nextInt());

            studentdatabase.add(currentStudent);

            Scanner continueInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 'C' to end or 'A' to Add More");
            cont = continueInput.next().charAt(0);

            //Prints out the arrayList
            System.out.println(studentdatabase);
        }
        while(cont != 'c' && cont != 'C');


        //sort the arrayList prior to printing
        studentdatabase.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getLastName));
        //studentdatabase.sort(Comparator.comparing(Students::getLastName).reversed());

        for (Student student:studentdatabase) {
            System.out.println(student.getLastName() + " " + student.getFirstName() + " : " + student.computeAverage());
        }

    }

}
```